# How to autolayout items in toolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, toolbar, landscape, autolayout

Items on toolbar in portrait mode look normal if you turn the landscape mode is that they shift.

How to make that they were in the middle in portrait and landscape mode?

Thank you all!

Comment: What items are in your toolbar? If they are buttons in iOS 5 in interface builder you can use autosizing in order to set their position so they rotate properly. If you are using iOS 6 then you have to work with constrains to lock their position and have them rotated.

Comment: In center i have segmented control, and buttons on the left and on the right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `Flexible Space Bar Button Item` on each side of your toolbar. That should push it to the center.